# C# Detect if WebBrowser lost connection to a website

Tags: c#, browser

I'm making a program that checks for alerts in a web page. I connect using the instruction:

```
Connect()
{
Browser.Navigate(url, "", enc.GetBytes(PostData), "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
...
}
```

and then I check for alerts every one second using this instruction:

```
GetMessages()
{
HtmlDocument doc = Browser.Document;
if (int.TryParse(doc.GetElementById("messages_count").InnerText, out msgs))
...
}
```

It works perfect but if I check that site with a traditional web browser then `GetMessages()` doesn't return the updated value anymore.
So what I did is create a second timer of 10 seconds interval that runs `Connect()` function so when the user visits the page the program won't be outdated for more than 10 seconds.

But it seems unnecessary to keep logging in all the time.. it would be better if I could detect when I need to run `Connect()` again instead of doing it all the time just in case. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY-problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). Have you considered to use `WebClient`, `HttpWebRequest` `HttpClient` `HtmlAgilityPack`?

Comment: Thanks.. I'll read about them and I'll come back if I have some trouble. I started with that simple way and worked just the way I wanted, but then I realized about the connection loss when accessing the site with a browser.

Comment: I've been reading about those keywords and their usage seems a lot more complex than the simple `Browser.Navigate` and `GetElementById`..
What would be the advantage of them over my code? Would it provide me a handler to the event of a connection loss or prevent the connection from being lost the way that is happening now?
I just feel like I need some deeper help than just providing me those keywords for me to investigate..